# Jquery hover help

Tags: jquery

The below code doesn't work. I want when the mouse hovers over a div with the class='row' to display the child div.  I'm used to JavaScript but i'm just now adjusting to jQuery.  How do i accomplish this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.block').hide();
$('.row').hover(function() {
$('.block').show();

});

});
</script>
<?php

echo "<div class='row'><div class='block'>one</div></div>";
echo "<div class='row'><div class='block'>two</div></div>";
echo "<div class='row'><div class='block'>three</div></div>";
echo "<div class='row'><div class='block'>four</div></div>";

?>
```

Comment: *facedesk* - Why are you echoing HTML? Just output it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code will currently show all elements with class "block" when any element with class "row" is hovered. You need to select the correct `.block` element:

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').hide();
    $('.row').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.block').show();
    });
});
```

This uses the `.find` method to find a descendant of the selected element that matches the selector `.block`.

I'm not sure what you intend to happen when the mouse leaves the `.row` element, but currently nothing will happen (in fact, the same `.show` line will run again, because that's what happens when only a single argument is passed to `.hover`). If you intended the `.block` element to be hidden again, you can supply another argument to `.hover`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').hide();
    $('.row').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.block').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.block').hide();
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can stick with the single argument, and use the `.toggle` method instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').hide();
    $('.row').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.block').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried this and  displays all divs.  It should only display on hover though?  I checked firebug and it says '$ is not defined'.

Comment: If `$` is undefined it is likely that you either have not included jQuery before your code runs, or that another JavaScript library has overridden the `$` function. Are you using any other JS libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the hover function you need to find the descendant of the current element, which you do like this:

```
$('.row').hover(function () {
  $(this).find('.block').show();
});
```

`this` is the current element (the hovered `.row` element), so `$(this)` creates a jQuery object out of that so you can call jQuery methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').hover(function(event) {
    if (this == event.currentTarget) {
        // run code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/theom3ga/yPCCn/

You just have to address the child block, using `$(".block", $(this))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').hover(function() {
  $('.block',$(this)).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').mouseenter( function () { 
    $('.block', this).show();
    $(this).siblings().find('.block').hide(); 
});
```

hover makes few sense in this case, except if you want to close the block altogether. this method allows to keep the last row open if you wander far away with your mouse.

http://jsfiddle.net/7SQdu/1/

hoever, if you want to close the block each time your mouse leaves:

```
$('.row').hover(  
    function () {
       $('.block', this).show();       
    },
    function () {
       $('.block', this).hide();        
    });
```

of course it implies something like `.block {display: none;}` in your css.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard for the user to perform mouseover on a hidden element (or an element that is very small).

Change your code to something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').hide(); // hide all .block elements
    $('.row').bind('mouseover', function() { // bind a mouseover handler
        $(this).find('.block').show();
    }).bind('mouseout', function () { // bind a mouseout handler
        $(this).find('.block').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why even use JavaScript? Why not just use CSS? (unless you really need to support IE 6 and below)

```
CSS:
.row .block { display: none; }
.row:hover .block { display: block; }

HTML:
<div class='row'><div class='block'>one</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='block'>two</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='block'>three</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='block'>four</div></div>
```

Oh and as `@Ben Everard` stated, no need for `echo`